# Working with Cisco WSMA from .NET

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wsma

I need to configure and query a Cisco router from my .NET application, and I need to do it by way of the Cisco [WSMA](http://www.ciscosysteme.com/en/US/docs/ios/netmgmt/configuration/guide/nm_cfg_wsma.html#wp1107680) web services interface.

These services are exposed over HTTP (in my case), and use SOAP 1.2 to enclose requests and responses (schema [here](ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/wsma/schema/)). So a call may look like this (example from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Management_Agent)):

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
  <SOAP:Body> 
    <request correlator="4.7" xmlns="urn:cisco:wsma-config" > 
      <configApply details="all"> 
        <config-data> 
          <cli-config-data> 
            <cmd>access-list 1 permit any</cmd>
            <cmd>ip hst foo 1.1.1.1</cmd>
            <cmd>no cns exec 80 </cmd>
          </cli-config-data>
        </config-data>
      </configApply>
    </request>
  </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>]]>]]>
```

This is all very cool, of course (certainly beats mucking around with telnet - AND it supports atomic transactions - all succeed or all fail - whereas CLI doesn't).

But up until now, I have been living in a comfortable .NET bubble where web services emit WSDL and I can build proxies in the client and things just work (or not ;-). There is no WSDL available, as far as I have been able to work out, and I don't quite see how to go about this.

- How do I configure WCF for something like this (set up a basicHttpBinding and a client endpoint)?
- How do I turn these schemas into contracts? By hand?
- Can SvcUtil do anything useful with those schemas?
- If I can create contracts somehow, does that mean I can generate proxies to work with, or will I have to work at a lower level?

I know as soon as I get some momentum, I'll get along fine. Can someone with similar experiences be a star and give me a few bullet points on how to go about this? Perhaps point me to some relevant blog post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XSD.exe to generate classes from provided XSDs. It seams that each file contains XSD for request, response and error, so each file represents single operation. Create service contract like

```
// ConfigXSDError, ConfigXSDRequests and ConfigXSDResponse are types generated by XSD 

// Message contracts are needed to avoid wrapping
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class ConfigResponse
{
  [MessageBodyMember]
  [XmlElement("response")]
  public ConfigXSDResponse Response { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class ConfigRequest
{
  [MessageBodyMember]
  [XmlElement("request")]
  public ConfigXSDRequest Request { get; set; }
}

// Other message contracts

// Service contract uses XmlSerializer instead of DataContractSerializer

[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true)]
public interface ICiscoRouter
{
  [OperationContract]
  [FaultContract(typeof(ConfigXSDError))]
  ConfigResponse Config(ConfigRequest request);

  // Other methods
}
```

Use [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) to create proxy for the service.

Answer (score 1):

One method that may work is to convert the XSD's that you have to a WSDL, for example by using this [XSLT tool](http://blog.springframework.com/arjen/archives/2006/07/27/xslt-that-transforms-from-xsd-to-wsdl/)

Comment: That could work. In this case, Ladislav's suggestion seems to fit best.