# SharePoint search service returns SERVER_ERROR (SQLException)

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a simple WCF webservice client that sends a request to Microsoft Search Server (included with SharePoint 2007) on `/more/_vti_bin/search.asmx`

The request is sent

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Query xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
<queryXml>&lt;QueryPacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query" Revision="1000"&gt; &lt;Query&gt; &lt;Context&gt; &lt;QueryText language="fr-FR" type="STRING"&gt;foo bar&lt;/QueryText&gt;&lt;/Context&gt; &lt;/Query&gt; &lt;/QueryPacket&gt; </queryXml>
</Query></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

But the response shows a SQLException error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<QueryResponse xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
<QueryResult>&lt;ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response"&gt;&lt;Response domain=""&gt;&lt;Status&gt;ERROR_SERVER&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;DebugErrorMessage&gt;System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException&lt;/DebugErrorMessage&gt;&lt;/Response&gt;&lt;/ResponsePacket&gt;</QueryResult>
</QueryResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: My question is simply: why do I have an error? There is nothing in the Application EventLog nor in the ULS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further analysis, I have understood that the problem lies in the fact that the Soap query does not start with an XML declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0">
```

This is perfectly possible and respectful of standards but SharePoint doesn't like that.

The question becomes: [How to force the WCF client to starts with an XML declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683350/wcf-client-does-not-include-xml-declaration-in-http-post-message).

Answer (score 0):

It states there's been a sql exception, coulld you check on your sql machine if any errors occurred?

Comment: There is no problem with SQL. The web interface replies correctly to search requests ; and the mossearch.com tool works.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with your request. test your search service using this [tool](http://www.mosssearch.com/searchwebservice.html)