# WCF client forgets XML declaration

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have written a WCF client for the SharePoint QueryService.

In a word, it writes a correctly-formed SOAP query. But when it is executed, the http request "forgets" the XML Declaration before the SOAP Envelope. The [QueryService does not like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750238/sharepoint-search-service-returns-server-error-sqlexception).

How can I force the WCF client to start the request with:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate (although some other web service) to [WCF client does not include XML declaration in HTTP POST message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683350/wcf-client-does-not-include-xml-declaration-in-http-post-message) .

It seems that you need to implement a custom encoder. See link above for more information.

Comment: It is a duplicate indeed (strange that I didn't stumple upon this question during my searches). Anyone having more than 250 points can safely close this question.